# Woocommerce how to check Radio Button when it needs to be active

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button, checked

I am trying to make a radio button active when the option is pressed. It's probably easy, but I've been having a time of it.

Here is the code:

```
 <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'tax_query' => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'terms' => 89,
                        'include_children' => false // Remove if you need posts from term 7 child terms
                    ],
                ],
            );
            $products = get_posts( $args );
            $product_start = 1;
            foreach($products as $product):
                $product_s = wc_get_product( $product->ID );
                if ($product_s->product_type == 'variable') {
                    if($c_p_id == '') {
                        $c_p_id = $product->ID;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <li class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 step1 <?php if($c_p_id ==  $product->ID) { echo "active"; } ?> ">
                        <a href="<?php echo $page_path; ?>?c_p_id=<?php echo $product->ID; ?>">
                            <div class="hldr">
                                <h2><?php echo get_the_title( $product->ID ); ?></h2>
                                <div class="img-hldr">
                                <?php echo  $image = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->ID ),  array('391', '266') , true );?>

                                <!-- <img src="<?php //bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/stand_alone2_375_250auto_bor8_ffffff_s_c1.jpg" alt="" />-->
                                    <div class="squaredFour">

                                    <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $product->ID ;  ?>" name="product" <?php if($product_start == $product->ID ) { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> class="checkTrack"> 
                            <!--  <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $product->ID ; ?>" name="product"  id="product" <?php if($product_start == $product->ID ) { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> class="checkTrack"> -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="txtDiv">
                                        <h3>Step1 :</h3>
                                        <h3>Traditional</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php
                }
                if($c_p_id ==  $product->ID) {
                    $tradi_product = new WC_Product_Variable($product->ID);
                    $tradi_default_attributes = $tradi_product->get_default_attributes();
                    $defaultProductId = $product->ID;
                }
                $product_start = 2;
            endforeach;
            ?>`
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to make the radio button active when it is in that variable please help.

I've been at it for hours and hours.

Comment: To change the client's DOM, when the client does sth, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code for this? I don't think it will work without JavaScript since PHP generates the code once and after that you need JS for checks like you need. Checkout this page to see how you can pass variables to JavaScript in WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's just `checked` (true or false) NOT `checked=checked`! Your html syntax is incorrect!

You could read more about radio input syntax:

> [html radio syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

If you need a `php` conditional check, then you could do something like this:

```php
<input type="radio" <?php echo ($product_start == $product->ID ) ? "checked" : "" ?> >
```